# DocuSign API Template Search by Name Limits

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently trying to utilize the [Templates list API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/list) with the `search_text` query string parameter. When I send a value that exceeds 48 characters, it will not return anything. Does anyone know if there is an assumed/imposed length restriction for using `search_text`?

Example GET Urls:

- **Works**: /Templates?search_text=Universal Power Purchase Agreement - Massachuset
- **Does not work**: /Templates?search_text=Universal Power Purchase Agreement - Massachusett

Answer (score 1):

You've crossed the maximum length of the `search_text` parameter. Trying to use a search term that's more than 48 characters will result in the search failing and zero results being returned.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll do this and keep this thread open until it’s fixed. Once fixed, I’ll post that it is so others will know.

Comment: To follow up, this issue was closed as 'Won't Fix', so it looks like the max length of search_text will remain at 48 characters.

Comment: Thank you for following up! Would you be able to provide some context around that decision?